# I want to use angular directive In react render function

Tags: reactjs, angularjs-directive

I have angularjs application and now I have added reactjs into my application but Now I get one confusion how to use angularjs existing directive in react js.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Let's I give example code.
I have one existing directive **fileselect** in angular js and i want to use this directive in react js render function like this:

```
render() {
    return (
            <div className="attach-documents-controller">
                <input id="file-upload" type="file" fileselect />
            </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I can't find solution for use angular directive in react js so i create react fileselect component and use this component right now.